# Strict Construction vs. Liberal Construction

Tags: criminal-law

What is the difference of meaning of the term "including but, not limited to" in the strict vs the liberal interpretation of the term?

Comment: There aren’t necessarily strict and/or liberal interpretations of every phrase. Adding “but not limited to” after the word including is sort of a safeguard against arguments that would say “because you didn’t include X in the list you provided after you said ‘including,’ then *only* those things you listed (and not X) apply/are affected.” You can think of “including but not limited to” as saying “the following is a non-exhaustive list of...”